# Webscraping in Python based on interactive chart

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape the data from the line chart on this [website](http://www.worldgovernmentbonds.com/cds-historical-data/argentina/5-years/) (link at the bottom) in Python.
My html understanding is very limited, and I have trouble finding the right elements of the code to obtain the data behind the graph.
My idea is to follow the logic from this [tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/web-scraping-101-in-python-35f8653b1c97).

And perhaps use input from this [tutorial](https://jensfoerderer.wordpress.com/2019/01/30/how-to-scrape-the-data-behind-interactive-web-graphs/).

Can anyone help me fetch the data?

Answer (score 0):

Data is sometimes concealed in HTML tags.
But most of the time, it is loaded by means of another dedicated request which returns JSON.
And it is the case for your site :) and fortunately it will be easier to process.

1. [Optional] Open *Chrome* in *Incognito mode* and [clear browsing data](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2392709).
   When scraping, it is always better to start from a completely new fresh session
   in order to avoid *side effects* when reproducing the navigation through the code.
2. Open *Chrome DevTools*
3. Go to *Network* tab and filter in order to get only XHR responses.
   Most of the time, other types of response are not interesting.
4. Enter [your URL](http://www.worldgovernmentbonds.com/cds-historical-data/argentina/5-years/)
5. Search for a request that could contain the precious data, briefly looking at their response.
   If it took time to fetch, it is plausibly *this* request.
   If it is of JSON type, it is probably *this* request.
   You may also take advantage of the *"Filter URL"* bar, where you could filter by entering:
   "ajax", "json" or "domain:www.your-domain.com".

[image: ajax request]

6. Once you get *the* request, copy its cURL and convert it to a Python request [here](https://curl.trillworks.com/).
7. Clean it, removing unnecessary cookies/headers (by testing your request).

Finally, you'll have:

```py
import requests

response = requests.get('http://www.worldgovernmentbonds.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=jsonStoricoCds&area=23&dateRif=2099-12-31&durata=5Y', verify=False)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was able to solve my issue (and others) with your help :)

Comment: Hi @mkalt, feel free to accept/vote the answer if you found it helpful :) thx